# Twilio: Using a TwiML app from another twilio account

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I have two twilio accounts.
On the first I created a TwiML app configured to use webhooks.
On the second one I have a number configured with the same webhooks as the previous app.
All the ivr steps work fine, but when I have to answer via browser to a call, I receive this error:

```
{code: 31002, connection: Connection, message: 'Connection Declined' ….
```

My goal is to have a unique app to handle different customer twilio accounts.
Is this possible or I have to create a Twiml app in every customer account?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure I fully understands your scenario. Can you please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve? When you write "... but when I have to answer via browser to a call, I receive this error..." - what exactly are you doing? are you trying to answer an inbound call using Flex? are you trying to answer the call using a WebRTC API?

There are elements in your reports which are missing. Please fill the missing gaps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).